# What are the little pedestal things for?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I keep finding little pedestals usually in people's house that I can look at and they seem to all say the name of an enemy on them. What are they for? How do they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These pedestal are for mini figures of Mario enemies.

You can get the figures at the crane mini game,  in the south east part of the village.